# nth-child() doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have one question about `nth-child()` and `nth-of-type()`, I have tried both variants, but neither works. Here is my code:

```
#commentdamcherirounded:nth-child(odd) {
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -o-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    width:680px;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-16px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-color:red;
}
#commentdamcherirounded:nth-child(even) {
    border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -o-border-radius:4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    width:680px;
    display:block;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-16px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-color:yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't have more than 1 element with the same ID!

Comment: I think there is only one, no? Unless I misread the `nth-child` declaration... ah, looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18301402/1091386 below is enlightening.

Comment: I would also suggest to declare the identical styles once. And only declare the different backgrounds using the pseudo classes. Makes it easier when you want to change, for example, the width of all the elements.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to miss the fact that `nth-child` is a pseudo-selector, added to a particular selector rule. This is how it's usually used:

```
ul li:nth-child(odd) { ... }
ul li:nth-child(even) { ... }
```

In your example, `:nth-child` is applied to an ID selector - and it's just not going to work that way, as you cannot have more than element with a specific ID in your DOM.

The solution depends on what you really need here: it's either swapping ID for class for the elements you want to style, and representing this in the CSS rule:

```
.commentdamcherirounded:nth-child(odd) { ... }
.commentdamcherirounded:nth-child(even) { ... }
```

... or moving ID one level up (i.e., to their parent) instead, then targeting direct children of that element, like this:

```
#commentdamcherirounded>:nth-child(odd) { ... }
```

Note the difference `>` symbol makes: with a simple whitespace, you actually will advance this `nth-child` rule to all descendants.

Here's [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yFBhZ/) to play with.

Comment: Or you could try just specifying `nth-child(odd)` since whatever doesn't apply would be `nth-child(even)`. There also seems to be a lot of overlap between the two specifications, so if you factorise it well it might look cleaner too.

Answer (score -1):

Create a CSS class instead.

```
.commentdamcherirounded:nth-child(odd) {
    border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -o-border-radius:4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    width:680px; display:block; margin-bottom:15px;
    position:relative; margin-top:-16px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y; background-color:red;
}
.commentdamcherirounded:nth-child(even) {
    border-radius:4px; -moz-border-radius:4px;
    -o-border-radius:4px; -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:4px;
    width:680px; display:block; margin-bottom:15px;
    position:relative; margin-top:-16px;
    background-repeat:repeat-y; background-color:yellow !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Although it is not a good idea to have more than one `id` with the same value, there is a way to make this work.

```
[id=commentdamcherirounded]:nth-child(odd)
{
   /* your css code */
}
```